# Terraform resource with the ID already exists error when running Azure DevOps pipeline with Github CICD

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, infrastructure-as-code

I was following the tutorial with this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ff0DoAmpv6w&t=5905s (Azure DevOps: Provision API Infrastructure using Terraform) T

This is his github code, and mine was very similar: https://github.com/binarythistle/S03E03---Azure-Devops-and-Terraform

The problem was when the resource group doesn't exist on azure, say I deleted it manually, running the pipeine creates it as well as my container instance. But when I execute the pipline again when I try to commit some code change and push to github, it shows

```
azurerm_resource_group.rg: Creating...
╷
│ Error: A resource with the ID "/subscriptions/xxxxx/resourceGroups/xxx" already exists
│ 
│   with azurerm_resource_group.rg,
│   on main.tf line 30, in resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg":
│   30: resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
```

Shouldn't it remember that a resource HAS been created before and skip this step - or perform some other action?

#### My observations

It looked like when the first time run, log shows there were some extra steps exceuted

```
azurerm_resource_group.rg: Refreshing state... [id=/subscriptions/xxxxx/resourceGroups/xxx]

Note: Objects have changed outside of Terraform

Terraform detected the following changes made outside of Terraform since the
last "terraform apply" which may have affected this plan:

  # azurerm_resource_group.rg has been deleted
  - resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
        id       = "/subscriptions/xxxxx/resourceGroups/xxx"
      - location = "australiaeast" -> null
      - name     = "myTFResourceGroup" -> null
    }
Unless you have made equivalent changes to your configuration, or ignored the
relevant attributes using ignore_changes, the following plan may include
actions to undo or respond to these changes.
```

The second time pipeline was ran, the log shows:

```
Successfully configured the backend "azurerm"! Terraform will automatically
use this backend unless the backend configuration changes.
```

but then the error mentioned above was shown.

Comment: It should remember if you have a way to read what is in the state file. If not, then there is no way terraform can know about what was already created. Also, posting someone else's code is probably not a good idea as we need to see your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

deleting the `.terraform` local folder to clean the cache, then run `terraform init` again and retry running the pipeline.